# Unable to update TKinter graph

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Colleagues,

I am designing a GUI with two buttons and one is to display a graph, hourly temperature.
The issue that I am facing is that I can not make a function(update_graph) that updates the value with self.after.

This part creates page 1 and i working fine, until I call update_graph

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()

        canvas = Canvas(self, width=400, height=400, bg = 'white')
        canvas.pack()

    # create x and y axes
        canvas.create_line(100,250,400,250, width=2)
        canvas.create_line(100,250,100,50,  width=2)

# creates divisions for each axle    
        for i in range(11):
            x = 100 + (i * 30)
            canvas.create_line(x,250,x,245, width=2)
            canvas.create_text(x,254, text='%d'% (10*i), anchor=N)

        for i in range(6):
            y = 250 - (i * 40)
            canvas.create_line(100,y,105,y, width=2)
            canvas.create_text(96,y, text='%5.1f'% (50.*i), anchor=E)

        self.update_graph()

    def update_graph(self):
# here is canvas create line that causes a trouble                     
        canvas.create_line(100,250,140,200, width=2)
        self.after(100,self.update_graph)


Whith this code I get an error "canvas is not defined".

If I add self to canvas in update_graph, I get

 self.canvas.create_line(100,250,140,200, width=2)
AttributeError: 'PageOne' object has no attribute 'canvas'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: thanks, was able to use your "divisions" loops for inspiration on my own

Answer (score 1):

`canvas` is only defined in the scope of the constructor (`__init__`) method. If you want to be able to access it elsewhere in the class, you need to make it an instance variable. Instead of,

```
 canvas = Canvas(self, width=400, height=400, bg = 'white')
```

make it,

```
 self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=400, height=400, bg = 'white')
```

now, everywhere else in the code where you reference `canvas`, change it to `self.canvas`. This should fix the problem.

On an unrelated note, a problem that I'm seeing in `update_graph` is that it calls itself recursively, or over and over. Perhaps you could change it to something like this:

```
    def update_graph(self):
        # This line is quite long. Maybe you could shorten it?
        self.after(100, lambda: canvas.create_line(100,250,
                                                   140,200, width=2))
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** My redefinition of `update_graph` only makes sense if you want one fixed line drawn. If you intend to add other functionality, such as periodic updates, the original code is correct, as Bryan pointed out.

Comment: @settwi: I think the "unrelated note" advice is wrong. Your solution using lambda doesn't have the same behavior since it will only draw the line once. Calling `update_graph` via `after` is exactly the right solution for running a function periodically.

Comment: @BryanOakley, `update_graph` draws a single line with fixed parameters. Isn't drawing it once enough? If it had more than one job to do, I wouldn't have included the comment. Perhaps OP intended to add other functionality, in which case I am wrong. Edited accordingly.

Comment: @Settwi: yes, drawing it once is enough for a fixed graph. The first part of the question mentions he wants it to update hourly so I assume he wants the update to happen on regularly scheduled intervals. Solving this problem is just the first step of many, I'm guessing.